# Card with vertical aligned content, and animated states

Tags: css, css-transitions, flexbox, vertical-alignment

What is the best way to vertically align content within cards, whilst still allowing them to animate on hover, to show different screens?

For example if I have cards, each with a front which is shown and a back which is faded in on hover:

```
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
      <div class="front">
        <i class="material-icons">build</i>
        <span>Item 1</span>
      </div>
      <div class="back">hello there</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
      <div class="front">
        <i class="material-icons">build</i>
        <span>Item 1</span>
      </div>
      <div class="back">hello there</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
      <div class="front">
        <i class="material-icons">build</i>
        <span>Item 1</span>
      </div>
      <div class="back">hello there</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then using this css:

```
.item {
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: tomato;
    margin: 0 auto 1rem auto;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

.item .material-icons {
    display: block;
}

.back,
.front {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

.front {
    opacity: 1;
}

.item:hover .front {
    opacity: 0;
}

.item:hover .back {
    opacity: 1;
}

.material-icons {
    font-size: 5em !important;
}
```

However after using position absolute, my vertical centering doesn't work, and i'm pretty sure this might not be the best approach!

You can see a half working version here:
http://jsfiddle.net/kmturley/8o29y7pd/26/

Thanks!

Comment: Did you notice that the demo outputs differently on Chrome and Firefox? But I can't say which is right or wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `transform` to do the centering. It works great with absolute position elements. You won't need flexbox at all.

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%; top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
text-align: center;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1354hzqb/

Comment: ah wow that's so much easier. I think I was overcomplicating my version! thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `top` position of `50%` and `transform: translate(0, -50%)` to your `.back, .front` classes.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons');

.item {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: tomato;
    margin: 0 auto 1rem auto;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

.item .material-icons {
  display: block;
}

.back,
.front {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

.front {
  opacity: 1;
}

.item:hover .front {
  opacity: 0;
}

.item:hover .back {
  opacity: 1;
}

.material-icons {
  font-size: 5em !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="front">
      <i class="material-icons">build</i>
      <span>Item 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="back">hello there</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="front">
      <i class="material-icons">build</i>
      <span>Item 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="back">hello there</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="front">
      <i class="material-icons">build</i>
      <span>Item 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="back">hello there</div>
  </div>
</div>
```